# RF: Replace ${SPACE},${EMPTY} and - values to '0'

Tags: python, robotframework

Currently working with Robot Framework List. 
I have a LIST like this `['Thu 2/22/2018', ' ', '-', '0.0000', '0', '', 'Fri 2/23/2018', '0', '-', '0.0000', '0', '+20 hr 28 min', 'Sat 2/24/2018', '37', '37', '0.0000', '37', '-10 hr 23 min']` I want to convert  ${SPACE},${EMPTY} and - values to '0'.  I am trying with below code but i am getting these errors

```
ValueError: Cannot convert index ' ' to an integer.
ValueError: Cannot convert index '-' to an integer.
ValueError: Cannot convert index '' to an integer.
```

here is the code

```
:FOR   ${x}  IN   @{OnlyList}
\  Log   ${x}   console=true
\   run keyword if  '${x}'== '${SPACE}'  Collections.set list value  ${OnlyList}  ${x}  0
\   run keyword if  '${x}'== '-'  Collections.set list value  ${OnlyList}  ${x}  0
\   run keyword if  '${x}'== '${EMPTY}'  Collections.set list value  ${OnlyList}  ${x}  0
```

Not sure how to convert. Pl help.

Answer (score 6):

`Set List Value` takes *index* as the second argument.

```
${i}    Set Variable    ${0}
:FOR   ${x}  IN   @{OnlyList}
\  Log   ${x}   console=true
\   run keyword if  '${x}'== '${SPACE}'  Collections.set list value  ${OnlyList}  ${i}  0
\   run keyword if  '${x}'== '-'  Collections.set list value  ${OnlyList}  ${i}  0
\   run keyword if  '${x}'== '${EMPTY}'  Collections.set list value  ${OnlyList}  ${i}  0
\   ${i}    Set Variable    ${i+1}
Log   ${OnlyList}   console=true
```

Comment: Robot provides a `FOR .. IN ENUMERATE ...` option so you don't have to manually  increment a counter: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-enumerate-loop

Comment: Thanks Jan Kovařík. This helps a lot

Comment: Agree with you too Bryan